# Wiped a hard drive and now I can't install an OS X on it?

Tags: macos, mac, display, operating-systems, formatting

I had 4 hard drives that I put in to my new computer and wiped them individually using the cipher command in Windows 7 and then formatting in the windows explorer. They all worked prior and I could drag and drop files after.

I'm trying to install Mac OS X Leopard on to a 6 year old Mac Pro that worked prior to having its hard drives removed. I inserted the hard drive, inserted the installation CD for Leopard, and booted from CD, but it just hangs indefinitely.

It sounds like the disk is being read but the monitor never displays a picture. I tried 3 different monitors (that all work with other computers) and both the DVI ports on the Mac Pro but the monitor keeps saying there is no input data to be read from the computer.

I'm not sure why this is happening. I had just recently used the computer until I had gotten my new computer and it worked fine but now it doesn't seem like it is sending any picture data to any monitors and I can't reinstall the OS as a result. I'm not sure if I can install MAC OS X on another computer and then reinsert the hard drive because this is our only MAC.

Thanks

Comment: When you hold the *Option* key while starting the Mac Pro, does it display a screen offering selection of boot device?

Comment: No I cannot get a picture at all on the monitor I tried.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you "wiped" the drives in Windows 7, have they been reformatted? A disk needs to be formatted as "Mac OS Extended" in order to be seen by the OS X installer.

Is it possible to reformat the drives? If you can boot from the CD, there should be a Disk Utility application available on the installation CD that will allow you to partition and reformat the drives.

Comment: Ah, yeah I forgot about that. Is it possible to format a drive as "Mac OS Extended" from a windows machine?

Comment: He doesn't even enter the installer, which should be possible without qualifying volumes to install it on.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to but I can't get a picture on the monitor to display. Just black.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  Instead of asking questions in your answer you should either comment on the post and ask them, or constructively give the answers based on scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Leopard DVD are you using? Retail DVDs will only start on computers that were release prior to the release of the DVD. If you're trying to use a restore DVD it must be the restore DVD for that model and not a different model's DVD.